# Java execution logic while using custom Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, execution

I have been trying to figure out flow while implementing special serialization(serialize even transient objects) but I can not understand the flow:

```
public class object1 implements Serializable {

int i = 2032423;
String str = "dssadsadsdfsfsdfczxc";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
transient testobject ob1 = new testobject();
String str2;
testobject ob2;
String sooo =new String("jbdskdbshxcbc");

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {


    try {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "serialTst.txt"));
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        object1 obj1 = new object1();
        obj1.ob1.str = "this guy is referred";
        oos.writeObject(obj1);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("serialTst.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        object1 obb=(object1)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(obb.str2);

        ois.close();
        fis.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream Aois)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Aois.defaultReadObject();
    str2 = (String) Aois.readObject();  

    System.out.println(ob1.str);
    System.out.println(sooo);    // Why Null here??
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream Aoos) throws IOException {

    Aoos.defaultWriteObject();
    Aoos.writeObject(ob1.str);
}
```

}

** why String sooo is null even when normal (String sooo="something") will be printed????**

If there is no instance is created of object1 class then how come readObject and writeObject got into execution??

Comment: @luigi thanks for taking interest, but your solution will work for sure, but i want to know why, what i proposed wont work???

Comment: You should have posted this comment in my answer, not in your question. Also, my name is with double G :).

Answer (score 1):

`ob1` wasn't serialized since it is marked as `transient`. Also, when deserializing an object, Java won't execute nor the constructor of the class nor the default values set to the fields, instead it will fill the `transient` fields with the Java default values i.e. `int` with 0, `Object` with `null`, so your `ob1` field value will be `null`.

To *fix* the code in `readObject` method, you should initialize the `ob1` field before using it:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream Aois)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Aois.defaultReadObject();
    str2 = (String) Aois.readObject();  //this is totally ok
    ob1 = new testobject();
    ob1.str = (String) Aois.readObject(); //this should work
    System.out.println(ob1.str);
}
```

Comment: @SachinVerma probably I didn't explain this well. In simple words, when deserializing an object, the `transient` object reference fields will have a `null` value (that's the default behavior when deserializing). Thus, when using `ob1` in your `readObject` method it will be `null`, so you need to create it before using it.

Comment: hey but String sooo is null too??

Comment: @SachinVerma it shouldn't. Can you post the complete code to make the evaluation?

Comment: hey you fixed the confusion about why ob1 was not initialized.(Thanks for this)
but STring sooo still returns null.
(Please see updated question)

Comment: @SachinVerma that's strange and it should not happend. Probably you're not executing the code you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

> so what i want to ask is why there is NullPointerException, why ob1
>   was not initialized?

De-serialization neither invokes `constructor` nor `instance initializer` of the given `Serializable` implementing class. That means, the member variables of the class which are declared as `transient` and hence not serialized are initialized to `default value` when the object is being created out from the stream of bytes via deserialization. In your case

```
transient testobject ob1 = new testobject();
```

won't be executed during `deserialization`. But since, the object is being created so going by [JLS12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) the fields must be initialized to default value. While deserialization all the fields(*not marked as transient and static*) of serializable classes `object1`  are restored from the stream and the `transient` variable (`ob1`) is initialized to default value `null`. That's why the following line:

```
System.out.println(ob1.str);
```

within your `readResolve` method is throwing `NullPointerException` because of `ob1.str`.

> So how those methods (readObject , writeObject) started their
>   execution

`readObject` and `writeObject` methods are called automatically by JVM to write and read the object respectively.

> why String sooo is null even when normal (String sooo="something")
>   will be printed????

No, `String` `sooo` can't be null until and unless you  make it `null` before serialization.

Comment: no String soo=new STring("whatevr") is not printed. you may check yourself

Comment: @SachinVerma: **No** `soo` is *not null*. What I think that the `NullPointerException` that you are getting is because of `ob1.str`. And you are misinterpreting it for `soo`. Or, perhaps this is not the program what you are running.